Failure to trigger Compose
I am a beginner, and my code might be a bit clunky;
I want to understand why the state object's reference has changed in updateCfg, but it still doesn't trigger recomposition.
This state object is an unstable type, so it should trigger recomposition when the reference changes, right? Before the assignment in updateCfg, _jsonCfg.value and cfg have equal values, and the settings member references the same List. Before the assignment, I printed their hashcodes, and they are different.

@Composable
fun Parents(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    val cfg by viewModel.jsonCfg.observeAsState()
    val state by viewModel.stateCfg.collectAsState()

    Column {
        cfg?.let {

            Text(text = "livedata Size:${cfg!!.list.size}")
            ChildComposableFunc(cfg!!) { newList ->
                viewModel.updateCfg(cfg!!.copy(list = newList))
            }


        }

        HorizontalDivider()
//
        Text(text = "State Size:${state.list.size}")

        ChildComposableFunc(state) { newList ->
            viewModel.updateState(state.copy(list = newList))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildComposableFunc(
    cfg: MyConfig,
    onCfgChange: (MutableList<Int>) -> Unit
) {
    Button(onClick = {
        cfg.list.removeAt(0)
        onCfgChange(cfg.list)
    }) {
        Text(text = "Sub!")
    }


}


data class MyConfig(
    var name: String,
    var list: MutableList<Int>
) {

}

class MyViewModel(inCfg: MyConfig) : ViewModel() {
    // LiveData 实现数据变化的自动通知和 UI 的更新
    val jsonCfg: LiveData<MyConfig>
        get() = _jsonCfg

    private val _jsonCfg = MutableLiveData<MyConfig>(inCfg)

    private val _stateCfg = MutableStateFlow<MyConfig>(inCfg)
    val stateCfg = _stateCfg.asStateFlow()

    init {
//        Log.d("ViewModelLocal", "Create A ViewModelLocal")
//        _jsonCfg.value = inCfg
//        // 监听 LiveData 变化并记录日志
        _jsonCfg.observeForever { newValue ->
            Log.d("ViewModelLocal", "LiveData changed: $newValue")
        }
//
    }

    fun updateCfg(cfg: MyConfig) {
        Log.d("ViewModelLocal", "updateCfg: ${_jsonCfg.value}")
        Log.d("ViewModelLocal", "updateCfg: $cfg")

        Log.d("CPKCPK1", "" + System.identityHashCode(_jsonCfg.value))
        Log.d("CPKCPK2", "" + System.identityHashCode(cfg))
        _jsonCfg.value = cfg
        Log.d("CPKCPK1", "" + System.identityHashCode(_jsonCfg.value))
    }

    fun updateState(cfg: MyConfig) {
        _stateCfg.value = cfg
    }

}

I want to understand what are the conditions that trigger recompose?
The following code works normally, but you just need to modify the ChildComposableFunc function. By creating a backup of the List to operate on, you can trigger a recomposition. In this case, the assignment in updateCfg and updateState will be two different values.

@Composable
fun ChildComposableFunc(
    cfg: MyConfig,
    onCfgChange: (MutableList<Int>) -> Unit
) {
    val tmpList = cfg.list.toMutableList()
    Button(onClick = {
//        cfg.list.removeAt(0)
        tmpList.removeAt(0)
        onCfgChange(tmpList)
    }) {
        Text(text = "Sub!")
    }


}

Why? Why does a change in a state object reference(cfg Or State) of an unstable type NOT trigger recompose , But a change in a List member reference Can  work OK?

First I do not understand what is ChildComposableFunc. You are calling updateCfg inside this function. This might be a conflict.Second, You need to use MutableStateFlow instead of MutableLiveData or LiveData. Change your jsonCfg in the view model like this:
private val _jsonCfg = MutableStateFlow<MyConfig>(null)
    val jsonCfg = _jsonCfg.asStateFlow()

then observe it like follow in your composable:
val cfg by viewModelLocal.jsonCfg.collectAsState()


I apologize for the error in the function name within the code; I have made the modifications.

I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. Could you check my problem again? thank you
